# Selenium WebDriver resets fields - java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to automate an insert. My view has 3 tabs with diferent fields. The test runs by filling the fields in each tab, returns to the firt one and submits the form. When webdriver fills the third one, and goes back do the first one, so it can submit the data, some of the fields are blank. 
In several of theese fields, I used this:

```
if(!isElementPresent(driver,By.xpath("//div[@id='tabView:frmGrid:depto']/div[2]/span"))){
    waitForElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='tabView:frmGrid:depto']/div[2]/span"));
}
```

Where theese methods are:

```
private boolean isElementPresent(WebDriver driver,By by){  
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  
 try {  
    driver.findElement(by);  
    return true;  
 }  
 catch(Exception e)  
 {  
    return false;  
 }  
 finally  
 {  
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  
  } }

public WebElement waitForElement(By by) {
    WebElement result = null;
    long maxTime = 6 * 1000; 
    long timeSlice = 250;
    long elapsedTime = 0;

    do {
        try{
            Thread.sleep(timeSlice);
            elapsedTime += timeSlice;
            result = driver.findElement(by);
        } catch(Exception e) {
        }
    } while(result == null && elapsedTime < maxTime);

    return result;
}
```

Even in fields where the primefaces component is there, has text "typed", when it goes back to the tab...it is blank..!But not all of them, curiously. But always the same ones. Text fields and dropdown lists. Haven´t seen similar problem around. Someone has an idea why?

Thanks!

Comment: it is extremely unclear what you are asking.. could you edit your question and elaborate?

Comment: sorry about that... i think it is better now.